# PostOperation Create Plugin needs to perform InitializeFromRequest and spits "Record does not exist"

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-365

I have a plugin developed (Post-Operation, Create, Sync) which grabs the `Target` and invokes `InitializeFromRequest` to create another record derived from the one being created.

Here is the stripped-down version of the `Execute` method:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
  IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
  IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

  var newRecord = (service.Execute(new InitializeFromRequest
  {
    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId),
    TargetEntityName = "my_entityName",
    TargetFieldType = TargetFieldType.ValidForCreate
  }) as InitializeFromResponse).Entity;

}
```

This worked perfectly until around a couple weeks ago.

Now the exact same plugin errors out stating `my_entity with Id = <guid> does not exist`.

I sort-of understand why it happens, I'm still inside the transaction and the record hasn't been *actually* created yet, hence the error.

I suspect April update is to blame because it started to happen around the time when the update was massively deployed on all environments (we, as usual, don't update unless we absolutely have to, being that updates always break a truck of random stuff).

Has something changed in how Post-Operation Create plugins are handled by the platform ?
Is this yet another undocumented tweak we'll need to somehow circumvent ?

Comment: I'd create a ticket with Microsoft Support if you think this was affected by April release and see what they say about it. In the meantime, you can probably workaround it changing the plugin to be asynchronous (and if it works you're going to be sure that there was a change in the plugin execution pipeline which it caused the issue in the first place).

Comment: I did open a ticket, if and when I hear back from them (in my experience this might take weeks) I'll self-answer this.